# Travis-CI openssl aes-256-cbc bad decrypt "Wrong final block"

Tags: encryption, openssl, travis-ci, travis-ci-cli

i use following travis-ci-cli command to create an encrypted-file:

```
travis encrypt-file src/env/data.ts src/env/data.ts.enc --add
```

It creates the file and related key and value on the Travis-CI.

You can see error of [travis](https://travis-ci.org/GeoMatDigital/app-geomat/builds/300933896)

Why do i get the `wrong final block length` here?

Comment: Probably because the data length isn't a multiple of 128 bits

Comment: How can i verify what is the length of my script (do we talk about the de- or encrypted one?) What do i have to change to make it 128-bit long?

Answer (score 0):

This error is a known problem when encrypting files using the Travis CLI on Windows.

Travis provides a guide [here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encrypting-files/#manual-encryption) that will help you encrypt your local files with a passphrase and then store that passphrase using `travis encrypt`.

If you'd rather not do that, you'll have to either use Windows Subsystem for Linux or use a Linux VM to run `travis encrypt-file`.